# How to remove items from window in ext js?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want remove all the items from the Ext window component. Means i have to clear the window in a button event.
Any help is must appreciated....Thankz

just

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

removeAll() method of window, which Removes all components from this container.

`window.removeAll()` or `Ext.getCmp('windowId').removeAll();`

refer : [Ext.Window-method-removeAll](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Window-method-removeAll)